# Pulling Data From An Array Into A Switch Array

Tags: arrays, json, swift, switch-statement

I'm trying to populate my picker view with data from JSON array. The array pulls the data in number form but, I need the String equivalent. I think the best way to do this is a Switch/Case statement to grab the data and put it in String form. From there I want to append that String to an Array. I'm not sure how to add it to this function.

This is the Data being pulled from the function:

```
tempProducts [{
  "product_id" : 27,
  "size" : 4,
  "id" : 45,
  "price" : 180
}, {
  "product_id" : 27,
  "size" : 3,
  "id" : 44,
  "price" : 90
}, {
  "product_id" : 27,
  "size" : 2,
  "id" : 43,
  "price" : 45
}]
```

This is the function:

```
func loadSizes() {
    Helpers.showActivityIndicator(activityIndicator, view)
    if let productId = product!.id {
        APIManager.shared.getProductsize(productId: productId, completionHandler: { (json) in
            print("API Print", json)

            if json != nil {
                self.prodSize = []

                //product_size is the name of the array that is passed (name of field in postman)
                if let tempProducts = json["product_size"].array {
                    for item in tempProducts {
                        let prodPrice = ProductSize(json: item)
                        self.prodSize.append(prodPrice)
                    }

                    print("tempProducts", tempProducts)
                    print("Prod Price", self.prodSize)

                    self.pricePicker.reloadAllComponents()
                    Helpers.hideActivityIndicator(self.activityIndicator)
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

ProductSize Class:

```
class ProductSize {
    //Label for product information

    var price:Float?
    var sizeId: Int?
    var size: Int?
    var product_id: Int?

    init(json: JSON) {
        self.price = json["price"].float
        self.sizeId = json["id"].int
        self.size = json["size"].int
        self.product_id = json["product_id"].int
    }
}
```

How would I turn size into a string using Case/Switch and then append that to an array?

Comment: post ProductSize class

Comment: @Sh_Khan posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slight variation on solution posted by @vadian that used a helper function instead. If I understand your question correctly, then a simple helper function could be used to add the calculated String value. Something like this should work (have not tested it).

```
struct ProductSize {
//Label for product information

var price : Float
var sizeId : Int
var size :  Int
var productId : Int
//computed Value
var sizeString : String

init(json: JSON) {
    self.price = json["price"].floatValue
    self.sizeId = json["id"].intValue
    self.size = json["size"].intValue
    self.productId = json["product_id"].intValue
    //computed value
    self.sizeString = self.sizeDescription(size: self.size)
}

//helper function
func sizeDescription(size:Int) -> String{
    switch size {
    case 2:
        return "small"
    case 3:
        return "medium"
    case 4:
        return "large"
    default:
        return "unknown"
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Apart from the point that you are using an additional member and a function you pirated my solution literally. :-/

Comment: @vadian yes, this it a variation of your solution, sorry, I should have mentioned that. I will update my comment.

Answer (score 1):

No need to create an array as you have an array of ProductSize

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView,titleForRow row: Int,forComponent component: Int) -> String?  {

    let item = self.prodSize[row]
    return getCategory(value:(item.size)!)

}
```

//

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    let sizes = [34,99,200]

    let result = sizes.map{getCategory(value: $0)}

    print(result)

}

func getCategory (value:Int) -> String {

    switch value {
       case 0...50 : return "Small"
       case 51...100 : return "Medium"
       case 101...1000 : return "Large"
       default:
        return ""
    }
}
```

Comment: What about the switch statement? How would I implement that within the function? I want to be able to give sizes a name(small, medium, large).

Comment: you need to sort the array after the for loop that appends

Comment: I'm not sure on how to do that. I do not understand the logic.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you don't need a class, a struct is sufficient and as the JSON contains always all fields declare all members as non-optional

To get a string value for the size add a computed property

```
struct ProductSize {
    //Label for product information

    var price : Float
    var sizeId : Int
    var size :  Int
    var productId : Int

    init(json: JSON) {
        self.price = json["price"].floatValue
        self.sizeId = json["id"].intValue
        self.size = json["size"].intValue
        self.productId = json["product_id"].intValue
    }

    var sizeDescription : String {
         switch size {
            case 2: return "small"
            case 3: return "medium"
            case 4: return "large"
            default: return "unknown"
         }
    }
}
```

Then return

```
return self.prodSize[row].sizeDescription
```

in `titleForRow:forComponent:`

---

If there are more sizes use an array

```
    var sizeDescription : String {
        let sizeArray = ["micro", "mini", "small", "medium", "large", "XL", "XXL"]
        return size < sizeArray.count ? sizeArray[size] : "unknown"          
    }
```